# I want make a textfield limit 3 number

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I want let the user can only input 3 digit。

I try to use [0,9]{0,3} to make sure the input can not be more than 3 digit, however, the [0,9] part work, i can not input sth like abcd, but the {0,3}part doesn't work, i can input more than 3 number such as 123456

```
    TextField textArea1 = new TextField();
    textArea1.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(new UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change>() {
        @Override
        public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change change) {
            String value = change.getText();
            if(value.matches("[0-9]{0,3}"))
            {
                return change;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }));
```

Comment: change.getText only applies to what changed, not the entire text

Answer (score 0):

Return the change if the change is zero or more digits and the control's text length is less than or equal to 3.

```
    TextField textArea1  = new TextField();
    UnaryOperator<Change> integerFilter = change -> {
        System.out.println(change);
        if (change.getText().matches("\\d*") && change.getControlNewText().length() <= 3) {
            return change;
        }

        return null;
    };
```

If you want to use `Matches` only, you need to use `getControlNewText()`.

```
    TextField textArea1 = new TextField();
    UnaryOperator<Change> integerFilter = change -> {
        System.out.println(change);
        if (change.getControlNewText().matches("[0-9]{0,3}")) {
            return change;
        }

        return null;
    };
```